# analytics workspace manager failing to start

Tags: oracle

[trying to start AWM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Aor.png)

I have tried many versions of analytics workspace manager but same result, I have this icon while starting awm.bat.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - when starting the application the loading screen appears and and then it hangs...

Comment: In debug the following thing arise:
`Exception in thread "AppInitialisationThread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.awt.Component.getPeer()Ljava/awt/peer/ComponentPeer;`
Such a negligable attitude from Oracle... Such a frustration...